# adding the number of referrals and referral id's into the MySQL DB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, ajax

I have setup a referral system, whereby a user enters their email address and can then refer a friend. The friend is given a unique url followed by a code, ie: example.com/FHF73H

The DB is setup as such;

```
email_id    email           code        ts
1       test1@test.com      98VIB15     2011-03-17 01:52:22
2       test2@test.com      412395D     2011-03-17 01:58:00
3       test3@test.com      6521298     2011-03-17 02:00:51
4       test4@test.com      3VJ7AB5     2011-03-17 02:01:02
```

I have htaccess setup so `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]` and I can then use `$_GET['_url'];` to get the referrer code.

For each user in the DB, I want to track:

a) A count of how many people have *visited* their referral link
b) A count of how many users have then gone on and *subscribed* (by entering their email address and submitting)
c) A comma-seperated column of the email_id's of the users who performed b).

Essentially 3 columns are required.

Where must each of the above (a, b, and c) be placed in the code to function the way I'd like? I'm also unsure how to code all that up in PHP and what certain-type of column properties are required in the MySQL database.
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: a BIG thank you for your help yesterday to achieve what has been done so far.

Answer (score 1):

**A)**

There are 3 ways you can count how many times a referral link has been clicked.

1. Every click made, always
   Everytime the URL is called, you update the value in your database. This means one person can continually click and it will all be stored. Intentionally or not.
2. Every independent click
   You'll store a cookie on the user, and only increase the count when this cookie is not present. This will prevent people from accidentally increasing the count if they click the link two times. However, they are still able to clear their cookies to increase count.
3. Every unique click
   Here you choose to store what IP the click came from, and only increase count when the IP is not already present in the database.

**B)**

You'll have to save a cookie (regardless of above method). In this cookie you'll save whatever ID this referral had in your database.

In extreme cases, you might want to save to a database instead of a cookie to prevent people from clearing their cookies as to fake not being referred by anyone or the user doesn't accept cookies at all.

There is, of course, the possiblity to not save anything at all, and have the user land directly on the registration page. But the referrers ID will be lost if the users leaves or changes page.

**C)**

I wouldn't use CSV on a RDBMS in this case, instead I would probably have a new table with user_id (the person who registered) and a referral_id (ID of the referral). CSV or serialized data can be needed sometimess, though.

**Summary**

The user clicks on a referral link, you save a cookie of the ID of the referral on the users browser and increase the click count of this ID in your database.

When the user submits the registration form, you check for a cookie, if the cookie is found, you increase the referral count based on what referral ID was inside this cookie,